# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not updating its values after SearchView OnQuerySubmit()

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to update a FirestoreRecyclerAdapter from a `SeacrchView` `onQueryTextSubmit()`. It shows a blank Recycler adapter after the submit is pressed but obviously works when the fragment is loaded. Please have a look at the codes first

**Adapter**

```
public class SpeciesDatabaseAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<SpeciesDatabase, SpeciesDatabaseAdapter.SpeciesDatabaseHolder> {


    public SpeciesDatabaseAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<SpeciesDatabase> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SpeciesDatabaseHolder holder, int position, @NonNull SpeciesDatabase model) {

        Picasso.get()
                .load(model.getImageone())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.smile_monk)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView);
        holder.commonName.setText(model.getCommonName());
        holder.scientificName.setText(model.getScientificName());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SpeciesDatabaseHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.admin_species_item,
                parent, false);
        return new SpeciesDatabaseHolder(v);
    }


    public class SpeciesDatabaseHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView commonName;
        TextView scientificName;
        public SpeciesDatabaseHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageSpecies);
            commonName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textCommonName);
            scientificName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textScientificName);
        }
    }
}
```

**FragmentActivity**

```
public class AdminSpeciesDatabaseFragment extends Fragment {
    AdminUtility adminUtility = new AdminUtility();
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference speciesRef = db.collection("species");

    private SpeciesDatabaseAdapter adapter;

    FloatingActionButton actionButton;

    //EditText search;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.admin_species, container, false);
        init(view);
        setUpRecyclerView(view, "");

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view;
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView(View view, String data) {

        if (data.equals("")) {
            Query query = speciesRef.orderBy("id", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<SpeciesDatabase> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<SpeciesDatabase>()
                    .setQuery(query, SpeciesDatabase.class)
                    .build();

            adapter = new SpeciesDatabaseAdapter(options);

            GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_adminspecies);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Search: "+data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Query query = speciesRef.whereEqualTo("commonName", data);//.orderBy("id",Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<SpeciesDatabase> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<SpeciesDatabase>()
                    .setQuery(query, SpeciesDatabase.class)
                    .build();

            adapter = new SpeciesDatabaseAdapter(options);

            //adapter.updateOptions(options);
            GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_adminspecies);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
            //adapter.startListening();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

    private void init(View view) {

        //searchText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        actionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonAddPost);
        actionButton.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), AddFeedActivity.class)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        View mView = this.getView();
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Submitted"+query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setUpRecyclerView(mView, query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Text Change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_admin_user:
                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class));
                getActivity().finish();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_admin_sign_out:
                adminUtility.signOutGoogle(getContext());
                getActivity().finish();
                break;

            case R.id.refresh:
                setUpRecyclerView(getView(), "");
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

I have tried case sensitive search and also have implemented a `TextWatcher` in place of a `SearchView` but the result is the same.

**I can't get why the adapter is not listening to the updates which are called via new `options`**

Please, guide me so that I can rectify my erroneous implementation or any suggestion would help